# Android Multiple Screen Flexibility

Tags: java, android, layout, compatibility

2-3 years ago, the Android developers used layout folders to specify the dimensions for different screen sizes. Like:-

- layout (default)
- layout-small (from 2.0″ to 3.7″)
- layout-normal (from 3.7″ to 4.3″)
- layout-large (from 4.0″ to 7.1″)
- layout-xlarge (from 7.0″ to 10.0″)

My question is that, **now**, what is the *convention*, or what are the *folders* where we need to place our layout in order to fit into all the screen sizes?

I have looked up Screen Support at developer.android but I did not find a sufficient answer.

Comment: Use  constraint layout to build responsive UI https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: Okay. I shall look up how to use constraint Layout. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work for you

as per documentation support for multiple screen use below folder.

```
layout-sw600dp ( For 7 inch tablet)

layout-sw720dp ( For more than 7 inch tablet)
```

Create these folder and put these folder in below given path

```
 res -->  layout-sw600dp --> Your xml file ( i.e res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml)

 res --> layout-sw720dp --> Your xml file ( i.e res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml)
```

For Smaller screen use default Layout folder.

Comment: Okay, so for devices between 5-7″, I'll use the default layout folder? In some places, I have also seen the usage of sw.

Comment: for devices between 5-7,  you can use default layout folder.

Comment: I updated my answer. create folder layout-sw600dp  and layout-sw720dp instead of  layout-w600dp and layout-w720dp.
If the available width is a concern for you then create folder layout-w600dp. for height create folder layout-h600dp.